# R Estimating parameters of binomial distribution

Tags: r

I'm trying estimate parameters **n** and **p** from Binomial Distribution by Maximum Likelihood in R.

I'm using the function `optim` from stats package, but there is an error.

That is my code:

```
xi = rbinom(100, 20, 0.5) # Sample
n = length(xi) # Sample size

# Log-Likelihood
lnlike <- function(theta){
log(prod(choose(theta[1],xi))) + sum(xi*log(theta[2])) + 
(n*theta[1] - sum(xi))*log(1-theta[2])
}

# Optimizing 
optim(theta <- c(10,.3), lnlike, hessian=TRUE)
```

> Error in optim(theta <- c(10, 0.3), lnlike, hessian = TRUE) : 
>      function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

Anyone done this? Which function used?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't know how to get to the answer, but I also don't see an error... Could you post it?? Your question should be more focused around how to fix the error over how to get to the solution. (Getting to the solution might be just fixing the error though..)

Comment: @ZheyuanLi This is an illustrative example for what I need.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thanks for remind me and for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr** you're going to get a likelihood of zero (and thus a negative-infinite log-likelihood) if the response variable is greater than the binomial N (which is the theoretical *maximum* value of the response).  In most practical problems, N is taken as known and just the probability is estimated.  If you do want to estimate N, you need to (1) constrain it to be >= the largest value in the sample; (2) do something special to optimize over a parameter that must be discrete (this is an advanced/tricky problem).

First part of this answer shows debugging strategies for identifying the problem, second illustrates a strategy for optimizing N and p simultaneously (by brute force over a reasonable range of N).

Setup:

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 100
xi <- rbinom(n, size=20, prob=0.5) # Sample
```

Log-likelihood function:

```
lnlike <- function(theta){
    log(prod(choose(theta[1],xi))) + sum(xi*log(theta[2])) + 
       (n*theta[1] - sum(xi))*log(1-theta[2])
}
```

Let's break this down.

```
theta <- c(10,0.3)  ## starting values
lnlike(c(10,0.3))  ## -Inf
```

OK, the log-likelihood is `-Inf` at the starting value. Not surprising that `optim()` can't work with that.

Let's work through the terms.

```
log(prod(choose(theta[1],xi))) ## -Inf
```

OK, we're already in trouble on the first term.

```
prod(choose(theta[1],xi)) ## 0
```

The product is zero ... why?

```
choose(theta[1],xi)
##  [1] 120 210  10   0   0  10 120 210   0   0  45 210   1   0
```

Lots of zeros. Why? What are the values of `xi` that are problematic?

```
## [1]  7  6  9 12 11  9  7  6
```

Aha! We're OK for 7, 6, 9 ... but in trouble with 12.

```
badvals <- (choose(theta[1],xi)==0)
all(badvals==(xi>10))  ## TRUE
```

If you really want to do this, you can do it by brute-force enumeration over reasonable values of `n` ...

```
## likelihood function
llik2 <- function(p,n) {
    -sum(dbinom(xi,prob=p,size=n,log=TRUE))
}
## possible N values (15 to 50)
nvec <- max(xi):50
Lvec <- numeric(length(nvec))
for (i in 1:length(nvec)) {
    ## optim() wants method="Brent"/lower/upper for 1-D optimization
    Lvec[i] <- optim(par=0.5,fn=llik2,n=nvec[i],method="Brent",
                     lower=0.001,upper=0.999)$val
}
nvec[which.min(Lvec)]  ## 20
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(nvec,Lvec,type="b")
```

[image]

Comment: Ben,  I'm very grateful to you for helping me. Just one more question. Do you think the method of moments is better than maximum likelihood for estimate **n**?

Comment: Maximum likelihood usually has better properties -- it definitely has better asymptotic properties.  Whether MM is good enough depends very much on your application.  Might be a better question for CrossValidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3):

**Why you get into trouble?**

If you do `lnlike(c(10, 0.3))`, you get `-Inf`. That's why your error message is complaining `lnlike`, rather than `optim`.

Often, `n` is known, and only `p` needs be estimated. In this situation, either moment estimator or maximum likelihood estimator is in closed form, and no numerical optimization is needed. So, it is really weird to estimate `n`.

If you do want to estimate, you have to be aware that it is constrained. Check

```
range(xi)  ## 5  15
```

You observations have range `[5, 15]`, therefore, it is required that `n >= 15`. How can you pass an initial value 10? **The searching direction for `n`, should be from a large starting value, and then gradually searching downward  till it reaches `max(xi)`.** So, you might try `30` as the initial value for `n`.

Additionally, you don't need to define `lnlike` in the current way. Do this:

```
lnlike <- function(theta, x) -sum(dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE))
```

- `optim` is often used for minimization (though it can do maximization). I have put a minus sign in the function to get negative log likelihood. In this way, you are minimizing `lnlike` w.r.t. `theta`.
- You should also pass your observations `xi` as additional argument to `lnlike`, rather than taking it from global environment.

**Naive try with `optim`:**

In my comment, I already said that I don't believe using `optim` to estimate `n` will work, because `n` must be integers while `optim` is used for continuous variables. These errors and warnings shall convince you.

```
optim(c(30,.3), fn = lnlike, x = xi, hessian = TRUE)

Error in optim(c(30, 0.3), fn = lnlike, x = xi, hessian = TRUE) : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
In addition: There were 15 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the 
first 15

> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE) : NaNs produced
2: In dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE) : NaNs produced
3: In dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE) : NaNs produced
4: In dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE) : NaNs produced
5: In dbinom(x, size = theta[1], prob = theta[2], log = TRUE) : NaNs produced
```

**Solution?**

Ben has provided you a way. Instead of letting `optim` to estimate `n`, we manually do a grid search for `n`. For each candidate `n`, we perform a univariate optimization w.r.t. `p`. (*Oops, in fact, there is no need to do numerical optimization here.*) **In this way, you are getting a profile likelihood of `n`**. Then, we find `n` on the grid to minimize this profile likelihood.

Ben has provided you full details, and I shall not repeat that. Nice (and swift) work, Ben!

Comment: I agree that we could just write down/solve analytically for p-hat given N, but the OP may have some reason to do this numerically/want to extend this to more complex examples.